# Angular directive scope is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Directive:

```
var ActorDisplayDirective = function() {
    return {
        replace : false,
        restrict : 'AE',
        scope : {
            actor : "="
        },
        templateUrl: staticContext + '/angular-app/templates/actor-display-template.html',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        },

    }
};
```

This works fine in some places, but not others.  Here is my code to show it where it is not working:

```
  <p>CAP: {{can_approve_for}}</p>
  <p>
Actor display template: 
<span actor-display actor='can_approve_for'></span>
After template
  </p>
```

The `CAP: ...` displays the data, the directive's `actor` value is null.  Why?  My controller does:

```
dataFactory.getCanApproveFor().then(function(data) {
$scope.can_approve_for = data;
});
```

So, I am able to see the value on the page, but the directive does not show it.  I'm assuming it's a timing/refresh thing, but this directive works elsewhere in `ng-repeat`, because the `ng-repeat` evaluates after hte object is already set, I guess.  How do I do it in this case?

Comment: Is `can_approve_for` a primitive or an object? Perhaps try using `controllerAs` instead of `$scope` and see if you can fix it that way

Comment: it's an object, and I don't know what `controllerAs` is

Comment: Using `$scope` is discouraged, `controllerAs` is the preferred way. See here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController. But can you post a demo to reproduce your issue? It'd be easier to test it if we can see it fail

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually declaring `ActorDisplayDirective` as a directive. Its just a plain function that returns an object that sort of looks like a directive.

You have to tell angular that it is a directive like so:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
    .directive('actorDisplay', function () {
        return {
            replace: false,
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                actor: "="
            },
            templateUrl: staticContext + '/angular-app/templates/actor-display-template.html',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            },
        }
    })
```

Comment: I do that, it works in other places and is used the same way, except in an ng-repeat loop

Comment: "I do that" ... maybe you should post your actual code then. Otherwise those that are _trying_ to help you are merely shooting in the dark and trying to solve problems unrelated to your original issue.

Comment: I have the line `app.directive('actorDisplay', ActorDisplayDirective);` in a file that does a bunch of static init stuff.  There are a few thousands of lines of code, and 40 or so directives.  I posted the relevant ones and missed that one.

Comment: Ok. A guess would be that your `getCanApproveFor()` method is async and doesnt return until the template is already rendered. Prob should use `ng-bind="can_approve_for"` instead and it will update the inner text. Having `scope.actor` seems superfluous and unnecessarily complicated imo.

Comment: How do I use ng-bind, then?  In the Directive, template, or what?